# how can I get a mysql result set that contains both matched and unmatched records

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join

I have the following tables:

```
suppliers
id  name
1   s1
2   s2
3   s3
```

```
products
id  name
1   ...
2   ...
..  ...
9   lemon
..  ...
```

and

```
product_suppliers
id supplier_id product_id  
1  2           9
```

I need a result set that looks like the following one:

```
supplierName     productSupplier
s1               null
s2               1 
s3               null
```

I tried a left join like the following one:

```
select * from suppliers 
left join product_suppliers on suppliers.id = product_suppliers.supplier_id
where product_suppliers.product_id = 9
```

but the result set contains just the lemon that is associated with the supplier s2 and I also need the rest of the suppliers for a future association.

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just move the condition from the `where` clause to the `on` part of the `left join`. Conditions in the `where` clause are mandatory, so if a record has no match in `product_suppliers` it will evict it from the resultset.

```
select s.name supplier_name, ps.id product_supplier
from suppliers s
left join product_suppliers ps on s.id = ps.supplier_id and ps.product_id = 9
```

I also modified your query to implement a few best practices:

- enumerate the columns in the `SELECT` clause
- use table aliases

Answer (score 0):

Remove the where condition, by doing that you are filtering just the product with id 9